# Explicitly backup selected files/folders with rsync

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, arch-linux

I want to make a backup of some specific files/folders of my $HOME to an external hard drive. I am using rsync with the following syntax:

*rsync -avh --delete-excluded --exclude-from=.backup.lst $HOME/ BACKUP/*

The backup.lst file includes the following:

```
    # Include
    + /Dev/
    + /Documents/
    + /Music/
    + /Pictures/
    + /.config/openbox/
    + /.config/tint2/
    + /.irssi/
    + /.mplayer/
    + /.backup.lst
    + /.bash_history
    + /.bash_profile
    + /.bashrc
    + /.conkyrc
    + /.fehbg
    + /.FehImage
    + /.htoprc
    + /.inputrc
    + /.rtorrent.rc
    + /.urxvtc.sh
    + /.vimrc
    + /.xinitrc
    + /.Xresources

    # Exclude
    - /*
```

Everything is synced properly except *.config/openbox/* and *.config/tint2/*

a) Is there some way to include these two folders?

b) In general, is the above syntax correct to properly backup these files? I would appreciate getting any other suggestions regarding backup with rsync.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried similar case myself. Apparently you've got to include the parents at all depths, and also remove the unwanted children using `- /<deep-parent>/*` in a later exclude rule(s) (at all the depths).

```
# Include 
+ /.mplayer/
+ /.config/
+ /.config/openbox/
+ /.config/tint2/

# Exclude
- /*
- /.config/*
```

Man page says the `.config/*` would not be considered at all if you dont put just `.config/` because of the exclusion of `/*`